# Importing a Python script within the same package, using a path containing the python package name in it

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path, python-module

I have a python package (empty __init__.py inside) with several scripts, let's call it "mypackage" for simplifying. Then, I have two scripts, one called "utils.py", one call "view.py". I want to import utils in view, but, depending on the computer I am using (both Windows 10, both WinPython, both PyCharm, both 64bit), only one import form works, from the following two:

```
import utils as u
```

OR

```
import mypackage.utils as u
```

Why are not both of them working?

Comment: Non eof the answers helped, unfortunatelly. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because one of your computers has python 2.x and the other has python 3.x. The way of importing modules in the same package changed with [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

The former way of doing this was with ambiguous relative imports

```
import utils
```

The problem is, does this refer to a module in the package or a stdlib module? This ambiguity meant that in python 3.0, it was decided that this syntax will *always* refer to installed packages in sys.path (known as absolute imports) and the syntax

```
from . import utils
```

To cope with this backward incompatible change, python introduced the

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

which you can put in python version >= 2.5 code at the top of your file and then can use the latter method.

As far as I am aware, `import mypackage.utils` should work so long as `mypackage` is in a directory in `sys.path`, so I think that should work no matter what.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explenation. I am actually using in both compters Python 2.7. An still, in one computer I can use option one, in the other computer I can use option 2.

Comment: Try using `from __future__ import absolute_import; from . import utils` on both. The issue is almost certainly to do with the way your `%PYTHONPATH%`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in python documentation:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> 1. The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> 2. PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> 3. The installation-dependent default.

When u write `import mypackage.utils as u` your mypackage directory should be specified in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.